# Is there a way for Fiddler JS formatter extension to work conditionally?

Tags: javascript, fiddler

As a JS dev, I very frequently use Fiddler tool. I also use its [addon](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/extensions.asp) JavaScript Formatter to nicely format minified files for debugging purposes.

However, the problem is that the JS formatter doesn't seem to be configurable at all, and works on "all-or-nothing" base.

**Problem:**

In my company, we sometimes bundle a lot of (not JS, but compilable to JS) files together, serve it as JS, and then, rely on that file format to parse them and load properly. This may sound strange, but it's to avoid having tens of micro files, and have a one bundle with all of them.

So basically, the file looks like:

```
//MAGICCOMMENT
//FILEID
markup
markup
...
markup
//FILEID
markup
markup
...
markup
```

and so on.

**Question:**

Is there any way to tell Fiddler **not to prettify** that files? We have a `//MAGICCOMMENT` in the first line, which is the same for all the multipart files, which can perhaps be used to detect it, but I don't know if and how can I make use of it.

PS: I guess we can't change the MIME type of the served files.

**Edit:**

I know the "Make JavaScript Pretty" option in `Rules` menu, which is added after installing the JS Formatter plugin. I want to make this option working conditionally (but: *at the time of sending data to the browser*, so I can put breakpoints in the browser on the prettified JS source, for all the files that I want to be prettified, i.e. the files other than the multiparts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, you can just disable the "Make JavaScript Pretty" item on the Fiddler Rules menu. When you want to beautify an individual JavaScript file, you can do so by right-clicking the session in the Web Sessions list and choosing Make JavaScript Pretty directly on the session.

Alternatively, you can disable the global option and have FiddlerScript conditionally format the JS File. E.g. inside Rules > Customize Rules > OnPeekAtResponseHeaders()

```js
if (oSession.oResponse["Content-Type"].ToLower().Contains("script")) {
  if (!oSession.uriContains("Combinedfilenameorwhatnot")) { 
     // Note this flag name is soon changing to X-Format-JS
     oSession["X-FIDDLER-JS-FORMAT"] = "yes"; 
  }
}
```

Comment: URL-based formatting works nice! Thanks! The small caveat is that I have to adjust the list and add the files inside CustomRules.js, but it shouldn't be a big deal.

BTW I've seen there exists a method `oSession.GetResponseBodyAsString()`, but it returns empty string -- the response body it's not available yet in `OnPeekAtResponseHeaders`, right? No way to circumvent it, and set the `X-FIDDLER-JS-FORMAT` after pre-reading the response?

Comment: Correct, you can't call GetResponseBodyAsString until the OnBeforeResponse event. You can generally set the flag during the Peek event because that's where the Content-Type header is.