# Fiddler JS formatter extension to format html conditionally

Tags: fiddler

Related to: [Is there a way for Fiddler JS formatter extension to work conditionally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819292/is-there-a-way-for-fiddler-js-formatter-extension-to-work-conditionally)

As far as i know that js formatter extension is based on [js beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) project, and js beautify support formatting html and scripts inside them but when i use the same code that is provided in the related question which is :

```
if (oSession.oResponse["Content-Type"].ToLower().Contains("text/html")) {
     oSession["X-FIDDLER-JS-FORMAT"] = "yes"; 
}
```

I would get a messed up html structure and firefox can't show the html properly 
If i used `X-Format-JS` instead of `X-FIDDLER-JS-FORMAT` flag in the code above, then no formatting happens at all, so how to make js formatter formats html responses ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Fiddler isn't based on JSBeautify and no, it doesn't support automatic formatting of JavaScript inside HTML.

Comment: Well, it would be good if you can improve it to support Html formatting